# How can I execute C code inside a .NET application?

Tags: c, .net

I'm into Embedded Software development, and write pure C code which are hardware device dependent.

Before our hardware device gets ready, I need to complete application modules of our embedded software, which won't be directly hardware dependent.

Is there any way where I can write and execute C code in a .NET environment (VC++ or C#), have some UI for simulating the application, debug with breakpoints and watches and once the logic is proven, get the C files and port those to hardware (of course with modified interfaces)?

Since I'm not an expert in .NET, I'm not sure if this can be done. 
If yes, what approach do people use?

Comment: Create a DLL project to host your C code, in your C# code use [DllImport].

Comment: Will the DLL allow me to execute my C code line-by-line? I might want to set breakpoints in my C code while debugging. Will I be able to do that?

Comment: Yes, that's what the Project > Properties > Debug tab, "Enable native code debugging" checkbox does.  Do search Google for a tutorial, it will save you a lot of trial-and-error.  Query for "c# pinvoke tutorial".

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot, Hans. I'll give it a try and put an update here.

Answer (score -1):

It is straight forward to link C and C++ code, just ask your favorite search engine, or the little search box at the top of this page.

Be sure to put

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
```

and

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

around your declarations in the C header files.

For C# I don't have personal experiences, sorry.

Comment: The question was about c# and not c++.

Comment: OP wrote "VC++ or C#"